# Laravel populate non null fields while creating

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel populate non-null fields while creating without a default value.

In users migration I added `$table->string('username')`.

What is the best way to auto-populate this?

Using boot/booted method within User model:

```
protected static function booted () {
        if (auth()->user()) {
            self::creating(function ($model) {
                $model->username = self::generateUsername(self::name);
            });
        }
    }
```

This doesn't work because the username column is not null and has no default value. I could add nullable or default value as something but that seems like a wrong thing to do.

Ofc, I can add on create as well

`User::create($request->validated() + ['username'=>User::generateUsername($request->name)])`

But I want to leave it to auto-populate.

Now I am not sure is `creating` method run on the start of creating or end..

Answer (score 0):

```
public function setNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['name'] = $value;

    $this->attributes['username'] = $this->generateUsername($value);
}
```

This solved it :D